# Is there a way for me to push my referenced object into an array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to push each object into an array when it is clicked.  I am able to get a reference of each individual object but I'm not able to push the object into an array. It tells me push is not a function. I've spent so much time trying to figure this out. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ordered = {};

  vm.menu = [{
    title: 'Pizza',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: true,
    price: 10
  }, {
    title: 'Tacos',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: false,
    price: 5
  }, {
    title: 'Onion Rings',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 2
  }, {
    title: 'Ice Cream',
    type: 'dessert',
    favorite: false,
    price: 11
  }, {
    title: 'Mac n Cheese',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 7
  }, {
    title: 'Salad',
    type: 'salad',
    favorite: true,
    price: 4
  }];

}).directive('section', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.ordered = {};
      element.bind('click', function(event) {
        console.log(scope.item);
        scope.ordered.push(scope.item);
      });

    }
  };
});;
```

```css
.left {

  float: left;

  width: 50%;

}

.right {

  float: left;

  width: 50%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

  <div class="left">
    <h2>Lists One</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.menu | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2>Lists Two</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.ordered | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: `$scope.ordered = {}` should be `$scope.ordered = []`

Comment: Why use a directive for that? It's not reusable at all, and all you would need is ng-click on the section.

Comment: Thank you but the $scope.ordered still is not appearing to be populated in the view

Comment: I wasn't able to reference each individual object any other way.  I'm trying to learn Angular. I'm not a pro. If you know a better way of going about this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `scope.ordered = {};` to  `scope.ordered = [];`

Comment: Why is scope.ordered not appearing on the DOM